# Querystring encryption - Different type of encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, cryptography

On an Asp.Net projet, I'm receiving requests from 2 different software with the querystring encrypted using different cryptos.

For example, the legacy software is calling :
http://mywebsite.com/request.aspx?Operation=LegacyStuff (encrypted in rc4)

The other software is calling :
http://mywebsite.com/request.aspx?Operation=NewStuff (encrypted in aes)

How can I identify the encryption type? I thought about adding a unique prefix to the AES bytes, but I'm not sure this is secure enough because it would allow someone to send stuff encrypted in RC4 if they figure it out. Also note that I can't change the legacy part, so it has to stay in RC4, sadly.

Comment: Can't you use 2 different QueryString key?

Comment: Your question contains too few details to answer adequately (so I will vote to close it) but why not just use SSL/TLS?